# Tile server on Windows?

Tags: tile-map-service

Unfortunately but i have to make a tile server on Windows system. I were already generated tiles. Now i want publish it.
Tiles volume can be big - around city with city's local area.
When i did same on Linux i used nginx. What a bes practice to do tile server o Windows?

Comment: Well as you already have experience with nginx why not use it? It can be installed on Windows as well (without cygwin).

Comment: @Matte i wanted try something new. But can not google anyting interesting. Nginx my last hope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this answer will apply to your use case since you said you already generated the tiles, but I've successfully been able to use [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) on windows to serve tiles generated from other sources (PostGIS and Shapefiles). Geoserver does includes [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/) which features a TMS service which may be what you're looking for.

Documentation for GeoWebCache included in Geoserver:

- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/index.html

Comment: Geoserver and gwc used Java. I have a negative experience with gwc becouse it's eats alot of server memory.

Comment: That's kind of true indeed. In my case that wasn't a constraint and I needed something easy and "ready to use". If this is a constraint for you, I understand that you would rather find another solution.